# Passing values from one ViewController to another in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to pass an `NSString` (`message`) from `ViewController` (sender) to `MyViewController` (receiver).

I created an instance of `MyViewController` in `ViewController` called `testViewContoller`, through which I am sending the `NSString` using the `setTitle:` method:

```
MyViewController *testViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[testViewController setTitle:message];
```

Here's `MyViewController.h`:

```
- (void)setTitle:(NSString*)title;
```

Here's `MyViewController.m`:

```
- (void)setTitle:(NSString*)title {

_testField.text = title;

}
```

I am not completely sure as to why this isn't working, but I think it has to do with `viewDidLoad` loading before `setTitle:` is called.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You have to instantiate the view controller using the storyboard

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by not working.  Put an NSLog for title in setTitle method.

Comment: Look up 'prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender'

Comment: The problem with this approach is, when you initialized the method and called the method "setTitle", _testField.text ,an UIKit property, which is not been initialized and setup until viewDidLoad method has been executed. You have to use property to set title and then use that property in your viewDidLoad method as follows _textField.text = self.title;

Answer (score 0):

Where is `_testField` created?  If it is in `viewDidLoad`, then it is `nil` when you call `setTitle`, which means it is a no op.  `viewDidLoad` is called when the view is added to a window, which means that if you just call `init` on a view controller `viewDidLoad` may never be called.

I would define a property on `MyViewController` that is the desired field text and then have `_testField.text = title` in `viewDidLoad`:

```
MyViewController *testViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
testViewController.testFieldText = message;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     // do something to initialize _testField here

     _testField.text = title;
}
```

Also be aware that `UIViewController` already has a property called `title` and overriding `setTitle:` might have side effects that you aren't anticipating.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically related to when the memory is allocated to the `_testField`.
If you are creating the `_testField` in `viewDidLoad` programmatically

```
MyViewController *testViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
testViewController.testFieldText = message;
```

These two lines would not help as memory has not yet been allocated to the `_testField so the text cannot come up.`Even if you create it on the story board and assign the string in method

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
    {

            SecondViewController *obj = segue.destinationViewController;
            [obj setTitle:@"New Title"];
    }
```

This would also be of no help as the memory is again not allocated. The simple solutions to this problem is:

1. Either access the view property of the `MyViewController` before setting the `_testField` for example:

   ```
   MyViewController    *obj = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
   [obj setTitle:@"New Title"];
   ```
2. Set the string in a `@property` in the `MyViewController`, and reassign the string from the property to the `_testField`.

And yes, `setTitle` is a property of `UIViewController`, if you customize it will mess with the default property. play safe... :)

Comment: Through the use of NSLogs I was able to notice that ViewDidLoad happens before setTitle, but the values only show after setTitle happens.

Comment: If you add any view related call only then it would get called first else, we need to save the string in memory location in the new viewcontroller.

Answer (score -1):

In first ViewController you have use this following

```
SecondViewcontroller *MyViewController = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewcontroller"];
MyViewController.Title = @"Welcome";
[self presentViewController:MyViewController animated:YES completion:Nil];
```

In secondViewcontroller use the following

secondViewcontroller.h file to edit

```
@interface SecondViewcontroller : UIViewController
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *Title;
@end
```

then print the Title value to secondviewcontroller

Comment: Downvote for the same reasons as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267387/pass-a-value-from-one-viewcontroller-to-another-in-objective-c/33476332#33476332 especially since the answers on this question already answer the question and provide a lot of information already.