# How to send data like NSString from AppDelegate.m to ViewController.m in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I need to pass NSString data from AppDelegate.m inside didReceiveRemoteNotification method and send it to my ViewController. I need to put NSLog inside viewDidAppear every time i receive a notification.

Comment: Can you please more information about your problem? What did you try?

Comment: you can use NSUserDefault.

Comment: I need to pass NSString data from AppDelegate.m inside didReceiveRemoteNotification method and send it to my ViewController. Display the data as a string somewhere in ViewDidApeear or ViewDidLoad NSLog(@"value: %@", getData);

Comment: @yataki try my answer its already i use in my project and working fine . if any query then tell me

Comment: @Himanshu: where can i enter the first 3 lines of code? sorry, i dont know where.

Comment: add first 3 line of my answer in appdelagates.h file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass a value from one ViewController to another in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267387/pass-a-value-from-one-viewcontroller-to-another-in-objective-c)

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya: i put comment in your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an expansion to @Himanshu's answer, if you're getting your `NSString` in your `AppDelegate` and it's something which you needs to preserve for further use, you can create a property and store it. There are multiple ways which you can follow to store / retrieve the values (example: `NSDictionary`). So choose the one which will make your life easy in future.

Then you can get a shared object for your `AppDelegate` and access to that property.

Adding his code to make this for future readers.

1. Add a property in your `AppDelegate.h`

   `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *strResponse;`
2. Add this in top of the `AppDelegate.h` (after import statement)

   `#define theAppDelegate ((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate)`
3. Update string value.

   **Inside AppDelegate.m**

   `self.strResponse = @"some response";`

   **Outside AppDelegate.m**

   `theAppDelegate.strLoadApi = @"some good response";`
4. You can access it whenever requires.

   `NSLog(@"%@",theAppDelegate.strLoadApi);`

<sub>P.S. This is not the best way to do achieve this. It's actually not recommended but I believe, you're learning iOS. So it's basic for you to start. However, you should read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23740925/1603234) to make your self ready for the future development.</sub>

Comment: what do you mean outside AppDelegate.m?

Comment: @Hemang: There's nothing inside the string when i tried to NSLog inside viewdidappear of viewcontroller.

Comment: @Hemang: i already put some value inside AppDelegate.m but when i tried to access the data to know if there is an output there is nothing. i tried it in your way...

Comment: @Hemang: I'm sorry if you cant get my point. What i really want is to update my TableViewController every time i receive a notification. That's why I need to check inside viewDidAppear method and put some logs to know if my tableviewcontroller.m receive data from appdelegate.m...

Comment: Thx its working. 

But do you have have alternative way to update my TableView except this code? 

UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    MainTableViewController *notificationViewController = [[MainTableViewController alloc] init];
    notificationViewController.recvString = str;
    [navController pushViewController:notificationViewController animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a property to the header file of your ViewControler

```
@property NSString *data;
```

And then in your AppDelegate.m when you load your ViewController you can set the value of the property

```
self.YourViewController.data = @"Your String";
```

Comment: I need to pass NSString data from AppDelegate.m inside didReceiveRemoteNotification method and send it to my ViewController. Display the data as a string somewhere in ViewDidApeear or ViewDidLoad NSLog(@"value: %@", getData);

Answer (score 0):

**Interface:**

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject  {

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myString;
...
@end
```

and in the .m file for the `AppDelegate` you would write:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
        MyViewController* mainController = (MyViewController*)  self.window.rootViewController;
        self.myString = @" Here your String ";

        return YES;
}
```

Then, in `viewcontroller.m` file you can fetch:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
someString = appDelegate.myString;  //..to read
appDelegate.myString = someString;     //..to write
NSLog(@"mystring is :- %@",appDelegate.myString);
```

Comment: would u add variable in app delegate for every value pass for every viewcontroller?

Comment: i want the string data came from didReceiveRemoteNotification method of appdelegate...

Answer (score 0):

**add first 3 line in your AppDelegate.h file**

```
#define theAppDelegate \
((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate)

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString* strLoadApi; // create one property that you want to use in another viewcontoller.
```

**Any viewcontoller you can set that value like and must be set before access / get value.**

```
theAppDelegate.strLoadApi = @"Hello";
```

**Any viewcontoller you can get that value like**

```
NSLog(@"%@",theAppDelegate.strLoadApi);
```

Comment: would u add variable in app delegate for every value pass for every viewcontroller?

Comment: yes you can pass it very where in controller but you have to write one line that NSLog(@"%@",theAppDelegate.strLoadApi); that print your appdelagates property value

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya: i tried this line of code 

NSLog(@"%@",theAppDelegate.strLoadApi);

inside viewdidappear of viewcontroller it doesn't work.

Comment: did you assign or set value in appdelegates or any other controller before you get that value ?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya: yes, i did. i have no idea what went wrong.

Comment: just update your your 2 controller method that you assign value and get value from appdelgates property .

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to take property in AppDelegate.h

```
@property(nonatomic) NSString *yourProperty;
```

Then in AppDelegate You assign the value to that property.

Then in your ViewController you can access that Property By:

```
AppDelegate * del = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication]. delegate

NSString *str = del.yourProperty
```

Now use this str to display on UI.

Comment: would u add variable in app delegate for every value pass for every viewcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

whenever u want to pass NSString add this code

```
 //find ur viewcontroller and set parameter
 for (UIViewController *view in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
    if (view isMemberOfClass:[yourViewController class]) {
        yourViewController *yview = (yourViewController *) view;
        yview.parameter = @"string";
        break;
    }
}
```

in yourViewController set getter setter for parameter

Comment: What if it's a `UITabbarController` based or a drawer based application. You should update your answer for all the cases.

Comment: However, your answer is not accurate, you're commenting everywhere about, taking more properties.. but what if, I need the same response in 10 view controllers? Will you add those properties in each view controller?

Comment: @Hemang for tabbar controller you can say self.tabbarcontroller instead of self.navigationcontroller and it will work for drawer based application.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *sData = @"data";
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:sData forKey:@"keyName"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
to get it back later

NSString *sData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
    stringForKey:@"keyName"];
```

Comment: its batter to use setvalue for string value not a object .

Comment: u can use setValue Func.

Comment: i tried that b4 its working but i need alternative way so that i can use it in the future when i want to pass a data like nsdictionary or nsarray...